# how to find a joined query for the following situation

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two tables named `branch` and `source`. Table `branch` contains the columns `b_id` and `b_name` and table `source` contains columns `s_name` and `b_code` where each row contain multiple `b_code` separated by commas. I want result of with fields `s_name` and `b_name`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *SQL* will be something like this:

```
SELECT source.s_name, branch.b_id
FROM source
INNER JOIN branch ON source.b_code = branch.b_id
ORDER BY source.b_code
```

I'm using *MS SQL* and the query have not yet be tested. Let me know if the results are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT s.s_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.b_name) AS 'b_name'
FROM `source` s INNER JOIN branch b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.b_id, s.b_code)
GROUP BY s.s_name
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d7d1/4/0

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT source.*,GROUP_CONCAT(branch.b_name) FROM source LEFT JOIN 
branch ON FIND_IN_SET(branch.b_id,source.b_code) group by source.s_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT source.s_name,GROUP_CONCAT(branch.b_name) 
FROM source 
INNER JOIN branch on FIND_IN_SET(branch.b_id,source.b_code) 
GROUP BY source.s_name;
```

Try this query.